# Removal of multiple fields and labels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jQuery and have been stumped by particular issue. I am dynamically adding 2 checkbox fields to a screen form using the code below:

```
var summon_search = "<br><br><br><label for='summon_search'>Search this resource from compatible products*</label><input type='checkbox' id='summon_search' >";
var summon_link = "<br><br><label for='summon_link'>Link direct from content items in compatible products*</label><input type='checkbox' name='summon_link'>";
$(summon_search+summon_link).insertAfter("#jstor_selection");
```

However I have had limited success when I want to remove these fields AND labels (which is dependant on another value) and replace them with new fields. The code below shows my best attempt so far. It does appear to remove the labels and first field, but for some reason the last field remains. Could someone please advise if they can spot anything I've done wrong, or perhaps supply a better example of handling this ?

```
if ($("#summon_search").length > 0 ) { 
    //Removal of Label and Field (Attempted) 
    $("label[for=summon_search]").remove();
    $("label[for=summon_link]").remove();
    $("#summon_search").remove();
    $("#summon_link").remove();
```

Any feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `name='summon_link'` to `id='summon_link'`, because `#summon_link` expects an id.

Answer (score 0):

if you see your code the summon_link variable give it a id instead of name like in the summon_search variable

```
 name=summon_link change it to id='summon_link'
```

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is to add these HTML string after object with Id 'jstor_selection', you can use like this

```
$("#jstor_selection").append(summon_search+summon_link);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give the `for=` value in quotes.

EDIT: to remove extra `<br>`, normally it is suggested not to use `<br>`

```
$("label[for='summon_search']").prev('br').remove()
$("label[for='summon_link']").prev('br').remove()
```

---

```
$("label[for='summon_search']").remove();
$("label[for='summon_link']").remove();
```

also in the suman_link input element you have given as `name`

```
<input type='checkbox' name='summon_link'>
```

either change this to

```
<input type='checkbox' id='summon_link'/>
```

or

```
$("#summon_link").remove();
```

to

```
$("input[name='summon_link']").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks to you ALL for the helpful info - all seems to be working now - the only slight issue I have is when I remove the elements - the space is left on page - is there anyway to pull up existing forms when fields are removed?    But Many thanks to you all

Comment: thats because you have so many <br> before labels. you can remove it by excuting $("label[for='summon_search']").prev('br').remove() and $("label[for='summon_link']").prev('br').remove() before executing $("label[for='summon_search']").remove() and $("label[for='summon_link']").remove()... updated in the code

Comment: Even better would be not to (mis-)use the `<br>` here in the first place.

Comment: you are welcome buddy.. I think you should mark the answer as accepted to denote that the answer helped you to resolve your problem.